# jQuery and IE not playing together well; Object doesn't support this property or method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Trying to use a simple jQuery form submissions wrapper;

```
$('#login_form').submit(function (e) {
return true;
});
```

Console: Object doesn't support this property or method

Works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, basically everything but IE.

Comment: What version of IE and jQuery?

Comment: IE9, IE11, jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Use a non-minified version of jQuery if it's inside the lib

Answer (score 0):

Check in the inner html of your form element, search non empty input tags:

```
<input></input>
```

instead of:

```
<input type='etc' />
```

[reference](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-submit-function-will-not-submit-form-in-ie)